# Can anyone please help me Identify the piece at the beginning of this video?

Tags: identify-this-song, classical-music

It sounds like a cello duet. Please help me!

Answer (score 3):

It appears to be a string trio (or quartet) by David Wall, but I cannot confirm.

A [list of soundtrack music](https://www.thetake.org/index.cfm?page_name=faq) can be found on the website for the film.